# Flutter network image image not found

Tags: flutter, dart

My app reads a URL from Firestore. This URL points to an image in Firestorage.

If the image gets deleted in firestorage, the app will continue to try to read the URL...

How can I catch this error?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you add your code to the question?

Comment: I am using Image.network(), I also tried FadeInImage.assetNetwork() but still getting error, which makes sense because firestore is still providing it with an URL.The problem is that URL is not pointing to anything (firestorage image is deleted).

Answer (score 0):

You can get the exception using `Image.network()` with `errorBuilder()` named constructor

Here is an example:

```
Image.network(
        'https://example.does.not.exist/image.jpg',
        errorBuilder:
            (BuildContext context, Object exception, StackTrace? stackTrace) {
          // Appropriate logging or analytics, e.g.
          // myAnalytics.recordError(
          //   'An error occurred loading "https://example.does.not.exist/image.jpg"',
          //   exception,
          //   stackTrace,
          // );
          return Text('ð¢');
        },
      ),
```

Reference [Image Widgets errorBuilder Property](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/errorBuilder.html)